# Windows Phone 7 dont show scripts or images

Tags: javascript, html, windows, windows-phone-7

I had a html website that I ported to android using a WebView for a quick demo. Almost all I had to do was to load the Index.html and set some properties to true.
But now I have to do the same thing with Windows Phone and I cant get the web to work.

I´ll explain that I have an assets folder with the html and another folder with the images, and js inside.

When i run the application I get the first Html page with plain text and the navigation to the other pages only display the titles.

I made some research and found about the Isolated storage but i dont know  if has something to do with my solution. This is my code:

```
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowserUnico.IsScriptEnabled = true;
        webBrowserUnico.IsGeolocationEnabled = true;
        var rs = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("assets/Carrusel/memoria.html", UriKind.Relative));
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(rs.Stream))
        {
            this.webBrowserUnico.NavigateToString(sr.ReadToEnd());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not add these lines in your question ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to store all my 500 images and js in the Isolated Storage and I had to change the Build Action of the images to Content. The methods to introduce my files into the isolated storage can be found in http://transoceanic.blogspot.com.es/2011/07/wp7-load-local-html-files-and-all.html

In that website there is also a template that you can use to get all the files on your folder
instead of writing all of them.